# What is the value of result?

Tags: scope, closures

I am wondering what the value of answer will be after calling the outerfunc. Especially interested in the reasoning behind it (e.g. Why is the return value of the innerfunc not replacing the value stored in var x in the global scope? ) Thanks!

```
var x = 10;

function outerfunc () {
  x = 20;
  function innerfunc () {
    var x = x + 20;
    return x;
  }
  innerfunc();
}

outerfunc();

var answer = x;
```

Comment: You could just try it...

Answer (score 1):

Re Why is the return value of the innerfunc not replacing the value stored in var x in the global scope?

Because you created a new var called x inside innerfunc.  Try removing the var from line var x = x + 20;

Comment: Ok but as soon as the innerfunc gets called, why wouldnt innerfunc start looking for the closest x in outerscopes, in this case x = 20 ?

Comment: Because by using the var statement inside innerfunc, you have a created  new variable called x that is within the scope of innerfunc.  The code has no need to search outside of innerfunc.  In short, you have created two completely separate variables.  The confusion you're seeing is because you named them both the same.  Remove the word var as suggested, and innerfunc should then find the outer-scoped instance of x.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a local var with same name as a global var, then the global var become invisible in that function.

```
function innerfunc () {
  var x = x + 20; // here there is no global x. so it is NaN
  return x;
}
```

See this

```js
var x = 10;

function outerfunc () {
x = 20;
function innerfunc () {
  var x = x + 20;
  alert("value of x in innerFun " + x);
}
innerfunc();
}
outerfunc();
alert("global value of x is " + x);
```